# save an object with django createview from a form and additional fields

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I'm confused about how to add **additional fields** in my_model that are **excluded** from my HTML form defined in **forms.py** while saving with **createview**!

models.py:

```
class My_model(models.Model):
    # attrs in the form that are saved already with now problem
    ...
    #attrs excluded in forms.py but I want to save them along with the form
    attr_1=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    attr_2_type=[('a','A'),('b','B')]
    attr_2=models.Charfield(max_length=8,choices=attr_2_type)
    ...
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("application:redirectin_pattern_name", kwargs={"pk":self.pk})
```

views.py:

```
class MyModelCreateView(CreateView):
    model= My_model
    form_class = MyModelForm
    template_name = "application/mymodel.html"
```

mymodel.html

```
<div class="row ">   
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                {% block form %}
                     <form method="post" action="{% url 'application:pattern_name' %}">
                {% endblock form %}
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {{ form.as_p }}
                    <input class="form-control btn-primary" type="submit" name="save" 
                       value="send your demand" />
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

here everything is working fine the form is showing and I can submit data and save it to the database then I get automatically redirected to the details page of the object I saved and all the details are correct I even checked passing ids of another object to see if it changes and show the details of each object called and it works too.

now I just want to save the remaining attributes of the model at the same time when I'm saving the form to the database.

as requested
forms.py:

```
from .models import My_Model

class MyModelForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=My_Model
        exclude=("attr_1", "attr_2")
        widgets={
            # i listed all the attributes that I need the user to 
            # fill and they all are being saved correctly 
        }
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns=[
    path('demand', views.MyModelCreateView.as_view(), name='patern_name'),
path('detils', views.MyModelDetailView.as_view(), name='redirectin_pattern_name'),
]
```

Comment: Please add your `urls` and `forms` to get the all idea.

Comment: here you go i updated the question I hope we found a soloution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved**

thanks for the interactions I solved it but I can't explain the code so I will just post it.

I made changes to views.py

```
class MyModelCreateView(CreateView):
    model= My_model
    form_class = MyModelForm
    template_name = "application/mymodel.html"

    def form_valid(self, form):
    # comment: this fn will return the data from the HTML form 
    # and add to it the missing attrs of the model then save it
        form.instance.attr_1='string I want to save'
        #to save a clean string pass it between '' not ""
        form.instance.attr_2='a'
        return super().form_valid(form)
```